# C# How to make a int variable a loop that changes when the loop has loopt one time?

Tags: c#

I have this code that calculates the price of a product. This needs to be done for four products but they all have different prices.

Important: the stock of the products is calculated with an 2d array (and loop, see code)

```
for (int product = 0; product < stringProducts.GetLength(0); product++)
{
    averageA[product] = 0;
    for (int day= 0; ddayag < productStock.GetLength(1); day++)
    {
        sumP[product] += productStuck[product, day];
    }
    tbDataProductTotalPrice.AppendText(string.Format("{0:0}\r\n", sumP[product] * 0.89 + "€"));
}
```

So the 0.89 needs to be a variable that changes every time the loop loops. For example: first time loop it is 2 and second time it is 1.2 and so further.

So my question is: How to make a int variable a loop that changes when the loop has loopt one time?

Comment: Where are those numbers (0.89, 2, 1.2, etc.) coming from? Are they the product prices? Put them in a dictionary or an array. Also, a 2D array is a poor choice of data structure for this (or essentially any) application.

Comment: you can have something like `var multiplier = /*set variable*/;`, then `sumP[product] * multiplier + "€";`. But we can't know from your code where the value of this multiplier is will come from.

Comment: @EdPlunkett These numbers are indeed prices. Like int ProductX = 1.3 . I know that 2d array is poor but I need it do it that way for the assigment.

Comment: That's regrettable. Your array of prices needs to be an array of `double` or `decimal` or `float`; there is no such thing as an integer equal to 1.3.

Comment: @Ortiga Is it possible that for every loop that var can change becease every product has another price.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Oops.. my bad. But when it is and double can it be done? Do you know how.

Comment: @dfsghjk and how is your model defined? Update your question with an sample of your array.

Comment: `double[] prices = new double[] { 0.89, 2, 1.2, 1.3 };` -- make sure that the first item in the array is the price of the first product, the second is the price of the second product, etc. Then in your loop, use `sumP[product] * prices[product]` instead of `sumP[product] * 0.89`. Also, I recommend you move the euro symbol into the format string: `string.Format("{0:0}€\r\n", sumP[product] * 0.89)`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks that worked for me!

Comment: @EdPlunkett when I do  `double[] prices = new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 } ` it times the ` sumP[product]`  by 2 and not by 1.

Comment: @dfsghjk No, when you multiply a x by 1.0, the result is x. Show the actual code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett                 `tbCosts.AppendText(string.Format("{0:0}€\r\n", sumP[product] * prices[product]));`

Comment: @dfsghjk, no, it doesn't. Clearly you have a wrong belief about what the actual value of `sumP[product]` is. You think `sumP[product` is x, but in reality it is 2x. Use the debugger to see what is really going on in your program with your variables and values... ([Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), 
[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/))

Comment: @dfsghjk That code isn’t sufficient to reproduce the issue. I guarantee you, you and I are infinitely more likely to make  errors in our code the the runtime is to make errors in arithmetic. Elgonzo has good advice.